# Get unique identifier for Windows monitors

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a setup with two regular displays and three projectors connected to a windows pc. In my win32 program **I need to uniquely identify each monitor** and store information for each such that I can retrieve the stored information even after computer restart.

The [EnumDisplayDevices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162609(v=vs.85).aspx) seems to return different device orders after restarting the computer. There is also [GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd692950(v=vs.85).aspx) which at least gives me the display's name. However, I need something like a serial number for my projectors, since they are the same model. How can I get such a **unique** identifier?

EDIT: This is the solution I came up with after reading the answer from user [Anders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3501/anders) (thanks!):

```
DISPLAY_DEVICEA dispDevice;
ZeroMemory(&dispDevice, sizeof(dispDevice));
dispDevice.cb = sizeof(dispDevice);

DWORD screenID;
while (EnumDisplayDevicesA(NULL, screenID, &dispDevice, 0))
{
    // important: make copy of DeviceName
    char name[sizeof(dispDevice.DeviceName)];
    strcpy(name, dispDevice.DeviceName);

    if (EnumDisplayDevicesA(name, 0, &dispDevice, EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME))
    {
        // at this point dispDevice.DeviceID contains a unique identifier for the monitor
    }

    ++screenID;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EnumDisplayDevices` with the `EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME` flag should give you a usable string. And if not, you can use this string with the SetupAPI to get the hardware id or driver key or whatever is unique enough for your purpose.

> Set this flag to EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME (0x00000001) to retrieve the device interface name for GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR, which is registered by the operating system on a per monitor basis. The value is placed in the DeviceID member of the DISPLAY_DEVICE structure returned in lpDisplayDevice. The resulting device interface name can be used with SetupAPI functions and serves as a link between GDI monitor devices and SetupAPI monitor devices.

Comment: For me, when I provide `EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME`, `DeviceID` simply becomes empty.